# linker error when overriding operator<< in visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, operator-overloading, linker-errors

I have a template class "LinkedList", and what I'd like to do is override the << operator, to print the contents of the list.

So I have a header file like so:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T> class LinkedList
{
    public:
        LinkedList<T>() { this->head = nullptr; listSize = 0; };
        ~LinkedList();
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& outputStream, LinkedList<T>& list);

        //we don't check if you're putting in a duplicate to keep the insert at O(1)
        //you're on your own if you do that
        void insert(T* item); 

        //O(n) worst case, O(1) best case, we move queried items to the front, to get more best cases
        T* find(T item); //returns nullptr if not found
        T* find(int key);

        T* first();

        //complexity same as find
        bool remove(int key);
        bool remove(T item);

        int length() { return listSize; }


    private:
        Node<T>* head;
        Node<T>* findItemNeighbors(int item, Node<T>* prev, Node<T>* next);
        unsigned int listSize;

};
```

And I have a class file, with the various implementations, and this guy:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outputStream, LinkedList<T>& list)
{
    Node<T>* current = list.head;
    while (current != nullptr)
    {
        outputStream << *(current->item) << " -> ";
        current = current->next;
    }
    return outputStream;
}
```

Now, problem is, when I try to compile. I'm getting a linker error, but only when I try to use the operator in main, like so:

```
LinkedList<Employee>* list = new LinkedList<Employee>();
Employee* test4 = new Employee("Alex", "Herbert", 1101);
list->insert(test4);
cout << *list << "\n";
```

And the linker error, in all its glorious clarity is:
[image: madness]

What am I missing here? Everything otherwise compiles fine, until I try to use the << operator on that type.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Everything I had written here is wrong.

The trick is how to deal with template friend functions, and how the compiler interprets them.
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends

TL;DR is that the compiler (okay I got some bones to pick with C++ compiler authors) assumes that the friend function is the regular type, not the template type.

So, for friend functions, this cute little guy goes in your function signature "<>"

Like so:

```
friend ostream& operator<< <> (std::ostream& outputStream, const LinkedList<T>& list);
```

Now the compiler looks for the properly typed function and it doesn't complain it can't find anything.